# openSSL removing old certificate?

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl

I created a CA key and certificate as well as a broker one but I believe there is an error in certificate. Is there a way to delete the certificate ca.crt such as sudo rm /filetofolder/ca.crt or just move the files into a wastebasket and would I need to delete something in /etc/ssl/certs or I can just do the first step?

Answer (score 0):

You could use find to search for the certs and keys with something like this:

`find / -name "nameofcertorkey.*" -exec rm -rf {};`

- -name of the file and * wildcard so it matches with everything that hits "nameofcertorkey."
- `-exec rm -rf {};` Deletes the files that `find` finds